# Sort Queue<T> in place

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, queue

**Note:** i have to use `.net 3.5`

So does anyone know any method for sorting `Queue<T>` in place. I mean without any additional memory.

I have a very large `Queue<T>` - it's the general reason why i need to use in place sorting. And solution like `.OrderBy()` doesn't match.

Also I mustn't sort the `Queue<T>` each time after enqueuing or dequeuing an element. I need to sort it only for special events.

Now I guess the only solution for this problem is custom implementation of the `Queue` data structure. Isn't it ?

Comment: Technically you could implement a O(n!) algorithm to sort the queue (by searching every time the minimum value and adding it to the end of the queue)

Comment: Since you can only access the first and last element, a Queue does not have sorting functionality. Maybe you can access the underlying array through reflection.

Comment: Or you can write totally unsafe code that uses reflection :-)

Comment: I can implement queue based on an array with sort method which will able to sort the private array

Comment: @isxaker Implementing a Queue is not that difficult. I'd say that's the most obvious solution.

Comment: @isxaker Note that the .NET queue is a very good piece of code... It uses an expandable circular array to store items... so if the number of items you add and the number of items you remove is nearly the same, it won't grow.

Comment: @isxaker in this case you will have to somehow preserve order of enqueue. Otherwise it will not be queue anymore after you'll sort the array.

Comment: Thanks everybody - I wanted get a sort of advice and I got it.

Comment: Note that you can copy and modify the "Microsoft" version of the `Queue<T>`: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/Queue.cs It is MIT licensed.